# How to apply function on multiple tuples in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, view

I have a view containing two columns of array.

```
select * from cj_of_skills
```

[image: view contents]

I want to find the union of the two columns for  which I have a function as

```
create or replace function set_union(A anyarray, B anyarray) 
returns anyarray as
$$
   select array(select unnest(A) union select unnest(B) order by 1);
$$ language sql;
```

I want to apply the function to the view but I am getting the following error

```
select * from set_union((select s1 from cj_of_skills ), (select s2 from cj_of_skills))
```

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Answer (score 0):

The following function returns an ordered set built from two arrays. If either argument is NULL, then the result will be NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_union (a anyarray, b anyarray)
  RETURNS anyarray STRICT IMMUTABLE
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS $FUNC$
  SELECT
    array_agg(element ORDER BY element)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      element
    FROM
      unnest(a) a1 (element)
    UNION
    SELECT
      element
    FROM
      unnest(b) a2 (element)) t;
$FUNC$;
```